# Laravel 10 + auth0 integration middleware issue

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, auth0, laravel-10

We were running Laravel 7.4 with auth0/login 6.1 and auth0/auth0-php 7.6.1 and auth0/php-jwt 3.3.4

We recently updated to PHP 8.2 with laravel 10, and the latest versions of auth0/login and auth0/auth0-php.

Our system has a lot of API calls inside the website that go through the middleware (like getting the user’s email and name once the user logs in and the like for example and showing it on the corner, among several other things.

I tried following the guide on the auth0 site, but it got me nowhere.

If I enable the auth0 middleware in the auth0.php config file I cant use standard laravel login since I get this error:

> Auth0\Laravel\Guards\AuthenticationGuard::login(): Argument #1
> ($credential) must be of type
> ?Auth0\Laravel\Entities\CredentialEntityContract, App\User given,
> called in
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php
> on line 340" trace: [{file:
> “/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php”,
> line: 340,…},…]

That means it’s trying to use auth0 for standard laravel auth.

If I disable the auth0 middleware, the laravel login works perfectly.

If I use the sso with the auth0 middleware enabled, it logs in on the web route, but not on the API one so I'm basically stuck in the login screen because its not letting me through.

Everything was working perfectly up until the update to laravel 10 and the new version of auth0…

Weird things to consider:

1.- I have added the guards (in auth.php) and middleware (in kernel.php) manually to test, but its the same result:

```
‘auth0-api’ => [
‘driver’ => ‘auth0.authorizer’,
‘provider’ => ‘auth0’,
‘configuration’ => ‘api’,
],
‘auth0-session’ => [
‘driver’ => ‘auth0.authenticator’,
‘provider’ => ‘auth0’,
‘configuration’ => ‘web’,
],

and provider:
‘auth0’ => [
‘driver’ => ‘auth0.provider’,
‘repository’ => ‘auth0.repository’,
],
```

for the kernel.php file
middleware groups:

```
Api: …
\Auth0\Laravel\Middleware\AuthorizerMiddleware::class,

web: \Auth0\Laravel\Middleware\AuthenticatorMiddleware::class,
```

Another weird thing to consider is:

Im using 2 users to test this, user A will log in using standard laravel while user B will try to log in using auth0.

If I log in using auth0 it returns me to the login screen instantly and only shows logged in on the web endpoints but not in the api/ endpoints.

But if then disable the middleware for auth0 so I can use the Laravel login and I log in (same computer) with the standard log in, it will succeed, but inside the dashboard I would see the Users B information (auth0) instead of the User A. But the API login for the auth0 user was not done… kinda weird.

Comment: Based on the error message, it sounds like your `User` model isn't implementing some interface that it should. Maybe [this](https://github.com/auth0/laravel-auth0/blob/main/docs/Users.md#custom-user-models) will help? You may want to look through the closed issues there as well.

Comment: I get that error when trying to use the standard Laravel login while the auth0 middleware is not commented inside the Kernel.php file, it's trying to force the auth0 middleware on my standard routes for some reason.

I do have a custom user provider, but all that provider does is get if the session is from auth0, get the email, and return the id to the standard Laravel User Provider flow. 

Also, when I activate the auth0 middleware, and try to log in using SSO, I get logged in the web routes, but not on the API ones (so it returns me to to the login page even though auth()->check() works.